# How to live stream 4 cameras to a flat screen TV

Tags: video, streaming, monitors, electronics, engineering

I wanted to live stream different views from 4 cameras at the same time on a flat screen TV or monitor. What materials would I need for such a project. I have seen home security surveillance setups in which 4 cameras are streamed live to a monitor, however two things that are very important to this project are:

1.) live stream quality

2.) monitor size (need ~50inch display)

3.) placement of stream views on display

If there are surveillance packages that accomplish these goals (especially flexible positioning of the 4 live stream views), feel free to point me to them. Also, I am new to this website so If this question is not a good fit for this thread, then where would it be a good fit? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like the Blackmagic Multiview: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/multiview or Matrox Quad-Split http://www.matrox.com/video/en/products/microquad/ or Decimator MD-QUAD http://decimator.com/Products/MultiViewers/MD-QUAD%20Quad-Split%20MultiViewer/MD_Quad.html

These units take HD-SDI input and can then display it on a HDMI (or SDI) display however you like.

So grab as many cameras as you need - you can decide what quality camera suits your needs. Get cameras with with SDI output for long cable runs. If they don't have SDI, you can get HDMI to SDI converters. If an SDI cable isn't long enough, you can get SDI/HDMI to Fibre converters that let you run fibre optic cable between your cameras and a multiview.

Any half decent multiview will let you use a computer to re-arrange the placement of the images on the screen.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what i ended up figuring out I'm going to have to do. Very glad that someone else can back me up. One more question about connections though. I need a high quality feed from all 4 cameras on the monitor. However, my budget for this project prohibits me from buying the expensive quad splitters. If I purchase a lower end quad splitter, hook up the 4 cameras via RCA cables, connect the monitor output to a SDI-HDMI converter, then the converter to the monitor, will the quality of the feed improve? Sorry I am new to all this so bear with me:) Thank you again.

Comment: Couldn't fit the answer fully in the comments, but: The rule of gargabe in, garbage out, applies here. If the input into the splitter is only a 480p analog signal, the output isn't going to be any better quality than that original 480p signal. An SDI to HDMI converter won't improve quality at all, it will just take whatever the SDI input is and convert it to HDMI, that's all.

Comment: That is a good rule of thumb to go by. So if I am using HD 1080p surveillance cameras and a high quality monitor, will the quality of the video be hindered by a low cost, lower quality quad splitter? Is there some sort of "perfect quality in perfect quality out" rule hopefully? Can the splitter even affect the quality of the video? Thank you for all your help. You are actually a godsend.

Comment: If the splitter is HDMI/SDI, it should look perfect as everything is staying digital. Just make sure your security cams actually have HD-SDI output. Don't expect miracles though, security cameras, even "1080p" ones often look awful, even though they do output a 1080p image.

Comment: Wow that's concerning... This is the quad splitter I bought: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B00108HEKK/ref=mp_s_a_1_1?qid=1437002001&sr=8-1&pi=AC_SY200_QL40&keywords=Quad+splitter&dpPl=1&dpID=317VbVsyX6L&ref=plSrch  i guess just hope for the best! Thanks!